# Install sandbox package from app

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, sandbox-solution

I have sandbox solution for SharePoint Online (wsp package without dll) and I want install this package from app (for simplest installation).

Is it possible?

Comment: I found, that you need to have a Full Access on site collection for upload solution in list "Solution Gallery". But Windows Store do not approve apps that required "Full Access".

Comment: You may want to add the above comment as an answer and then accept it to close this question out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found, that you need to have a Full Access on site collection for upload solution in list "Solution Gallery". But Windows Store do not approve apps that required "Full Access".

Answer (score 0):

You can install an App from the 'Your Apps' page.  If you have user profiles setup anyway, not sure if its possible if those aren't set up.  The other option is to use an App Catalog, which is like an internal App Store, so you control it (Or the SharePoint Admin does).  Here is a link for other options:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179933.aspx